# R - graphics cross lines

Tags: r

I am with this doubt, but honestly I do not know if the solution really exists in R.

I have a graph x/y, and I want to draw two straight lines, (1) from the x-axis to the data, and another (2) from the y-axis to the data. Line 1, I have the value of it, would be the tertile of my data. The question is, how to find the exact point at which the line intersects the given and plot by following the y-axis?

I have already tried, by the position of the x-axis, to use the same position for y. This even works for some data, but not all (since the values ​​do not always match).

Here is my example

```
 ob<-c(77.89824, 170.36929, 90.88129, 141.22368, 174.07871,
 106.51393, 94.32576, 85.31712, 78.95808, 222.30143, 115.25760,
 85.84704, 165.33504, 72.06912, 38.94912, 90.88129, 167.18976, 
 125.85600, 141.22367, 104.65922, 131.95009, 81.07777, 
 64.12032,130.36032, 89.29152, 65.97504, 40.27392, 64.38529, 
 113.40288)

 tm<-c(38.94912, 40.27392, 64.12032, 64.38529, 65.97504, 72.06912,
 77.89824, 78.95808, 81.07777, 85.31712, 85.84704, 89.29152, 
 90.88129, 94.32576, 104.65922, 106.51393, 113.40288, 115.25760, 
 125.85600, 130.36032, 131.95009, 141.22367, 141.22368, 165.33504, 
 167.18976, 170.36929, 174.07871)    

 bs<-c(0.96523390, 0.93066061, 0.89634466, 0.86213300, 0.82769878,
 0.79311455, 0.75831596, 0.72311471, 0.68800759, 0.65245482, 
 0.61700818, 0.58163643, 0.51021060, 0.47393336, 0.43788203, 
 0.40203755, 0.36614804, 0.33059801, 0.29408090, 0.25820874, 
 0.22265365, 0.18803136, 0.15444785, 0.11931985, 0.08411248, 
 0.05098459, 0.01957279)

 prc<-c(0.956974397, 0.914559074, 0.872836231, 0.831624652, 
 0.790544222, 0.749700646, 0.709038330, 0.668364230, 0.628275180, 
 0.588180704, 0.548730882, 0.509909531, 0.433282681, 0.395329802, 
 0.358306283, 0.322222487, 0.286868665, 0.252670119, 0.218461386, 
 0.185847964, 0.154593177, 0.125303855, 0.098121311, 0.071199383, 
 0.046104574, 0.024746731, 0.007529233) 

 plot(tm,bs,type="l",col="red")
 lines(tm,prc,col="black")

 tinf<-quantile(ob,prob=1/3)
 tsup<-quantile(ob,prob=2/3)

 idxinf<-which(tm>=(tinf-5) & tm<=(tinf+5))
 infgrafico<-mean(prc[idxinf])
 idxsup<-which(tm>=(tsup-5) & tm<=(tsup+5))
 supgrafico<-mean(prc[idxsup])

 segments(tinf,0.03, tinf,infgrafico,col='black',lty=3,lwd=1)
 segments(min(tm),infgrafico, 
 tinf,infgrafico,col='black',lty=3,lwd=1)
 text(tinf,cex=1,y=0,col="black",font=2,"T1")
 segments(tsup,0.03, tsup,supgrafico,col='black',lty=3,lwd=1)
 segments(min(tm),supgrafico, 
 tsup,supgrafico,col='black',lty=3,lwd=1)
 text(tsup,cex=1,y=0,col="black",font=2,"T2")
```

But this is it, sometimes the values ​​are not corresponding and are not found, causing the straight lines do not cross in the value of the data. And yes, I would need something more automated as possible, as I have to save those values ​​on a table, and could not do it on the hand / trial and error one by one.

Thanks!

**EDITED AFTER ONE ANSWER**

TavoGLC or who wants, can you help in one more think? I have problems in some cases of my data.

```
tm <-c (54.05184, 67.29985, 70.86991, 78.42816, 80.84780, 80.54784, 80.81280, 81.8774, 89.82144, 89.82144, 90.81314, 90.35136, 92.20607, 92.47104, 97.50528, 97.77025, 99.09504, 99.88993, 100.41985, 100.94976, 101.74465, 102.27456, 105.45408 , 105.71905, 116.05248, 118.43713, 122.94144, 125.06112, NA)

prc <-c (0.9454304, 0.9604309, 0.9604309, 0.9608306, 0.9608306, 0.9608309, 0.9608309, 0.9608309, 0.9604309, 0.9605930, , 0.4163839, 0.3624935, 0.3041409, 0.2327866, 0.1079731, NA)

tercil <-89.821

plot (tm, prc, type = "l")
abline (v = 89.821, col = "red")
```

Considering that the line ('' abline (h = ...) '') has a very large range of location, when I do the procedure of "MakeLineCoords" obtaining values ​​of "2.627424", not agreeing with my data (max=1). I have a series of tm and prc data of [360,181,29], this example above is one of the errors I have cut. But if you want I can send you the complete test data.

This is the adaptation I made to work here.

```
yTinf = array (NA, c (360,181,29))
xTinf = array (NA, c (360,181,29))
   for (i in 1: 360) {
   for (j in 1: 181)
   for (k in 1:29)
      yTinf [i, j, k] <- tercil [i, j, k]
      xTinf [i, j, k] <- MakeLineCoords (prc [i, j,], tm [i, j,], yTinf [i, j, k])
}}}
```

Even so, it presents some values ​​greater than 1 and some extrapolated, in the order of 2000 and 3000. Which from what I realized, it would be due to the above problem, where xTinf contains some correct values.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to create a function that finds the closest point in the data and make an interpolation from that point.

```
MakeLineCoords <- function(Xvals,Yvals,targetPoint) {
  x <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(Yvals))
  for(k in 1:length(Xvals)){
    x[k]<-(Yvals[k]-targetPoint)^2
   }
  mL=which.min(x)
  xVal=Xvals[mL]+(targetPoint-Yvals[mL])*((Xvals[mL+1]-Xvals[mL])/(Yvals[mL+1]-Yvals[mL]))
  return(xVal)
  }
```

Then you can define a target value to be found and create the coordinates for the lines in the plot.

```
yTarget<-0.25
xTarget<-MakeLineCoords(tm,bs,yTarget)

plot(tm,bs,type="l",col="red")
segments(xTarget,0.0,xTarget,yTarget,col='black',lty=3,lwd=1)
segments(min(tm),yTarget,xTarget,yTarget,col='black',lty=3,lwd=1)
```

By using your example data i get the following. Hope it helps

[image]

```
tinf<-quantile(ob,prob=1/3)
yTarget<-tinf
xTarget<-MakeLineCoords(bs,tm,yTarget)
plot(tm,bs,type="l",col="red")
segments(yTarget,0.0,yTarget,xTarget,col='black',lty=3,lwd=1)
segments(min(tm),xTarget,yTarget,xTarget,col='black',lty=3,lwd=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you TavoGLC! But in this case, I need to use the values ​​of '' tinf '' and '' tsup '', because they are the values ​​of 33% and 66% of my data. These values ​​can't be change. I need to find the exact value on the y-axis that represents my 33% and 66% of my data on the x-axis.

Comment: I just updated the answer, you can use tinf and tsup as the target value to be found in `MakeLineCoords`. Also you can find the corresponding value over the x axis ot¡r the y axis by inverting the arguments of the function.

Comment: Thank you so much TavoGLC. But could you explain me your logic to development the function? You use the coordinates after and before the target point? I want make another analysis, and I would like to understand the function in more detail.

Comment: The idea is to find to closest point to a value (tinf or tsup) and use it for interpolation. For that, the distance from each data point to the value is calculated and stored in x. Then the location in the data of the closest data point is obtained with `which.min(x)`. With that location, I can select the closest points to the target for the interpolation. Over `MakeLineCoords` I select the closest point and the next point to the closest one for the interpolation.

Comment: If you imput `MakeLineCoords(X,Y,Yval)` will return the interpolated X value and with  `MakeLineCoords(Y,X,Xval)` will return the interpolated Yval. Hope it helps